# SUM function when using multiple tables not working right

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT psparcomp.ps_comp,
  MPA_Desc.Side,
  MPA_Desc.Color_Code,
  MPA_Desc.Description,
  sum(ISNULL(Forecasts.schd_discr_qty, 0)) AS [Order Amount],
  Product_Structure.pt_promo,
  Forecasts.sod_nbr,
  SUM(PaintSched.qty) AS schedamt
FROM MPA_Desc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN psparcomp ON MPA_Desc.MPA_Number = psparcomp.ps_comp
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Forecasts ON psparcomp.ps_par = Forecasts.sod_part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Product_Structure
    ON psparcomp.ps_par = Product_Structure.pt_part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PaintSched ON MPA_Desc.MPAID = PaintSched.MPAID
WHERE Forecasts.schd_discr_qty > 0
GROUP BY psparcomp.ps_comp,
  MPA_Desc.Side,
  MPA_Desc.Color_Code,
  MPA_Desc.Description,
  ISNULL(Forecasts.schd_discr_qty, 0),
  Product_Structure.pt_promo,
  Forecasts.sod_nbr
```

And these are my results:

[image: Results]

I need the results to just show "MPA-0856" and a total summed for the order amount. It's pulling multiple times because from the forecasts table, the part numbers it's pulling are different part numbers, but these are painted parts that are used on multiple part numbers. I'm creating a report for our paint department here and they only need to see the total amount that they need to paint instead of amount by part number. I've tried this a couple of different ways on joins but nothing seems to work. Can anyone assist?

Comment: please share sample table data and output from that

Comment: My apologies the screen shot is from that, will that not suffice? Would you need a different screenshot?

Comment: Something we can copy and paste, and not having to type ourselves would help alot. Ideally if you could provide the insert scripts.

Comment: Images are not good for sample data or desired results. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 What is much better is providing consumable data. Something like this. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sounds good I don't care to do that but I apologize I'm not entirely sure *how* to do that. Just run it to text, copy and past to my original post?

Comment: If we could just copy and paste your code, and it works out of the box, without us having to setup code/create scripts outselves removes removes points of failure, and effort on our side. So, Instead of working off your actual tables, as you did above, work from temp tables. Then, insert test data in those temp tables. Provide us with that entire script, ie, the creation of the temp tables as well as the insert scripts.

Comment: I gotcha, I appreciate the reply and you guys taking the time to help me out. I really need the help but I apologize I'm not sure of an easy way to do that. I don't care to do that at all, but these tables are from linked servers, and there's thousands of rows to make all of this. Is there some form of command I can run in SQL to make that feasible that will create that temptable with data in it so I could link it to here? My aplogies on being new to this.

Comment: Mocking up a quick example of your database structure and some fake data to illustrate your issue would go far to helping. A good place to use would be http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Window Function. (https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/)

```
SELECT psparcomp.ps_comp,
  MPA_Desc.Side,
  MPA_Desc.Color_Code,
  MPA_Desc.Description,
  sum(ISNULL(Forecasts.schd_discr_qty, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY .... ) AS [Order Amount],
  Product_Structure.pt_promo,
  Forecasts.sod_nbr,
  SUM(PaintSched.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY ..... ) AS schedamt
FROM MPA_Desc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN psparcomp ON MPA_Desc.MPA_Number = psparcomp.ps_comp
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Forecasts ON psparcomp.ps_par = Forecasts.sod_part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Product_Structure
    ON psparcomp.ps_par = Product_Structure.pt_part
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PaintSched ON MPA_Desc.MPAID = PaintSched.MPAID
WHERE Forecasts.schd_discr_qty > 0
GROUP BY psparcomp.ps_comp,
  MPA_Desc.Side,
  MPA_Desc.Color_Code,
  MPA_Desc.Description,
  ISNULL(Forecasts.schd_discr_qty, 0),
  Product_Structure.pt_promo,
  Forecasts.sod_nbr
```

Comment: Hey man I appreciate the help. I'm getting an error on this: https://i.imgur.com/aX2RQCt.jpg

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Does the link above in my comment not work? It appears in that statement after the "(PARTITION BY ..... ) " that second parenthesis it's underlining, doesn't like it on both of those statements

Comment: Ah, didn't see the link. Don't use `...` in the `PARTITION BY`. You'll want to use the columns you're actually grouping on.

Comment: I'm dumb. My bad. Will work on it and get back to you. Sorry

Comment: I've never used this, according to the example would I need to write the joins etc. in the partition by or just simply call from the existing structure already such as forecasts.sod_nbr

Comment: To follow up; This round about fixed it. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing: it seems that your GROUP BY clause **shouldn't** list this item:

```
ISNULL(Forecasts.schd_discr_qty, 0)
```

as that is part of the sums made.

Also, remove from group by and select any item that could possibly split your results among different rows (eg. colour, side, etc.)